# PostgreSQL delete group by

Tags: postgresql, sql-delete

I have a PostgreSQL 11 database. The snapshot of the table 'book' is below. My real database consists of 200 rows PER timestamp instead of the four in this example..

```
timestamp  ask_price     bid_price
18:00       5                4
18:00       6                3              
18:00       7                2
18:00       8                1
19:00       6                5 
19:00       7                4
19:00       8                3
19:00       9                2
```

I want to delete everything but the first two rows per timestamp to decrease the size of my database. The results should look like this:

```
timestamp  ask_price     bid_price
18:00       5                4
18:00       6                3              
19:00       6                5 
19:00       7                4
```

I tried the following query:

```
DELETE FROM book 
WHERE ctid IN (
SELECT ctid FROM book 
GROUP BY timestamp 
ORDER BY ask_price DESC LIMIT 2)
```

However, this returns the following error:

```
ctid must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```

How can I delete the rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using something like `ROW_NUMBER` to isolate the top two rows from the rest of the rows per timestamp.  We can try the following:

```
DELETE
FROM book b1
USING (
    SELECT ctid,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp ORDER BY ask_price DESC) rn
    FROM book
) b2
WHERE
    b1.ctid = b2.ctid AND
    b2.rn > 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using something like this also ?

```sql
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_table(
   ctid int
);

FOR temprow IN
    SELECT distinct(timestamp) from book
LOOP
    SELECT ctid INTO temp_table FROM book where timestamp = temprow ORDER BY ask_price DESC LIMIT 2 
END LOOP;

DELETE FROM book where ctid IN ( select ctid from temp_table);
```